# How to exclude a file from analyzing by Android Studio for a Flutter project?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am using Android Studio for my Flutter program, and I want to include a dart file like what the [Flutter Gallery app](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/gallery/example_code.dart) does, such that I [use it as an asset](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/pubspec.yaml#L87) instead of it being part of my program. How can I do that? A workaround is to use a file extension like 'txt' instead of 'dart', but that is not great.

I tried marking the file as plain text by right-clicking on the file, that does not help. I can bear the error warnings, but Android Studio does not allow me to reload the program if that file cannot be compiled (shown below).

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an option for `analysis_options.yaml`

```
analyzer:
  exclude:
    - "path/to/the/file/to/exclude.dart"
    - "or/pattern/**/*.dart
```

but it's not fully working yet.

See
<strike>https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34053</strike>
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/25551
for more details.

Comment: I cannot find any post is this fixed already?  I have problem to exclude automatically generated file from  flutter_localizations (i18n.dart).

Comment: I think it's not fixed. There is some bigger rework planned they want do before that or something like that.

Comment: Works just fine for me. Just be sure that you put your pattern or path into quotation marks.